# Best way to update Support Library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Till now(30-Nov-2017) google has released android support lib version 27.0.2 and Android Api version 27(Preview). Right now my application have `Target version 25` , `Build tool version 25.0.3` and `Compile sdk version 25`. I am planning to update my **Support Lib** as well as **Compile sdk version to 26**. So my questions are
1. Is Support lib version is related to android Api version means I am not updating android api to 27 because it is in preview so should I uses support lib 26.x.x or 27.x.x(which is latest).
2. which build tool version should i use means

Comment: use support library 26.x.x  if targeting api 26

Comment: If you want to use latested tools and face some errors too go for the review versions and secondly if you want to use stable versions go api 26. Just update your api's in gradle and sync you are good to go.

Comment: @Umair so Support lib is related to android api version means Support lib 27.x.x for android api 27 only

Comment: @AnkurSamarya yes support lib is related to android API versions. :) You will have to update them too

Comment: Please check out this post, it should help https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for API **level 26**. Because **API 27** is in preview mode so it won't be stable for now. Change your **Build.gradle** file like this and sync you are good to go.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "Your app ID"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
```

And you will have to update your dependencies too because they won't work in latest versions if you use the old ones. So that's why supp lib is related to android API.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Then why I get "Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details"

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah you should update your build version of Sdk to latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your 2nd question : You can use latest build tool version 27.0.1

`buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'`

You first need to download it from sdk.